# How get the record count of having status all 1's

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm saving person image in one table, one person will have multiple images, each image will have status 1 or 0, we need to get the record based on image status. if the image status of a person record is all 1's then we need to consider that record if any one of the status is 0 then we need to skip the record from the result

```
Original Result

id psqno status
1   1     1
2   1     1
3   1     0
4   2     1
5   2     1
6   3     1
7   3     0
8   4     1
9   4     1


Expected Result

id psqno status
1    2     1
2    4     1
```

I have tried the query like below:

```
select count(distinct psqno) as image_record from users where status = 1
```

I would like to get the count of result whose image having all status as 1.

Comment: why not id 4,5,6  8 , 9 ???

Comment: I need psqno and status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to find groups for which no other status exists:

```
SELECT psqno
FROM t
GROUP BY psqno
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*) -- all rows have status = 1
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=249590b26a2d49fce1c0e5a61434d13f)

Comment: with this query i'm getting all psqno's, i want only 2 and 4

Comment: If i want to get the count of those result then?

Comment: count not based on individual psqno, based on resulted count example count is 3 for the above result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192570/discussion-between-salman-a-and-user3668438).